# jQuery UI slider comma separated values

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery UI slider plugin to filter some divs based on the price,
in the slider i want the prices to be Formatted with a comma separated values when showing the output.

**HERE's the jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery('#slider-container').slider({
                range: true,
                min: 1200,
                max: 34000,
                values: [1200, 34000],
                create: function () {
                    jQuery("#amount").val("$1,200        -        $34,000");
                },
                slide: function (event, ui) {
                    jQuery("#amount").val("$" + ui.values[0] + "        -        $" + ui.values[1]);
                    var mi = ui.values[0];
                    var mx = ui.values[1];
                    filterSystem(mi, mx);
                }
            })
        });

        function filterSystem(minPrice, maxPrice) {
            jQuery("li.column").hide().filter(function () {
                var price = parseInt(jQuery(this).data("price"), 10);
                return price >= minPrice && price <= maxPrice;
            }).show();
        }
```

When i put a comma value in slider values like this `values: [1,200, 34,000],` the slider stops working, doesn't even load afterwards.

how to just show the values as comma separated?

looking forward for your answers :)

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use toLocaleString() on your output

[here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vepramjy/4/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery('#slider-container').slider({
                range: true,
                min: 1200,
                max: 34000,
                values: [1200, 34000],
                create: function () {
                    var val = "$1,200        -        $34,000";
                    console.log(val);
                    jQuery("#amount").text(val);
                },
                slide: function (event, ui) {
                    var val = "$" + ui.values[0].toLocaleString('us-US') + "        -        $" + ui.values[1].toLocaleString('us-US');
                    console.log(val);

                    jQuery("#amount").text(val);
                    var mi = ui.values[0];
                    var mx = ui.values[1];
                    filterSystem(mi, mx);
                }
            })
        });

        function filterSystem(minPrice, maxPrice) {
            jQuery("li.column").hide().filter(function () {
                var price = parseInt(jQuery(this).data("price"), 10);
                return price >= minPrice && price <= maxPrice;
            }).show();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Dan, in your fiddle the slider values have comma, but right after the range is slided the comma is replaced with a dot (which represents as a decimal in prices) i don't want the dot instead it should be a comma

Comment: If the locale is changed, will it work? like `de-DE` would become `us-US`??